# Why did RandomizedSearchCV raise the error when I use it to search parameters in TF 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

My code is as such, I try to search parameters in TF 2.0 used the KerasRegressor API.

```
def build_model(hidden_layers = 1,
                layer_size = 30,
                learning_rate = 3e-3):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation='relu',
                                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
    for _ in range(hidden_layers - 1):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layer_size,
                                     activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer)
    return model

sklearn_model = tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(
    build_fn = build_model)
callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, min_delta=1e-2)]
history = sklearn_model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train,
                            epochs = 10,
                            validation_data = (x_valid_scaled, y_valid),
                            callbacks = callbacks)

from scipy.stats import reciprocal
param_distribution = {
    "hidden_layers":[1, 2, 3, 4],
    "layer_size": np.arange(1, 100),
    "learning_rate": reciprocal(1e-4, 1e-2),
}

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

random_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(sklearn_model,
                                      param_distribution,
                                      n_iter = 10,
                                      cv = 3,
                                      n_jobs = 1)
random_search_cv.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train, epochs = 100,
                     validation_data = (x_valid_scaled, y_valid),
                     callbacks = callbacks)
```

However it end up with the error:

> Cannot clone object
>   , as the constructor either does not set or
>   modifies parameter layer_size

In my view, I have contained the parameter layer_size.

What should I do to solve this problem? also, when I change the "n_jobs" > 1, it can't work.

Answer (score 1):

This an issue in Kera's scikit learn wrapper, which can be solved in the following way:

1. Find your tensorflow's folder installation and the file *tensorflow\python\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py*
2. Edit the file in the line 117:

remove: `res = copy.deepcopy(self.sk_params)`

add:  `res = self.sk_params.copy()`

It basically switch from a deep copy to a shalow one.

Source [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/41341/files).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but it seems like there is a bug in the cloning process due to the way Keras' scikit learn wrapper returns the parameters (see [`get_params`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L108)).

[An issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13586) is opened about it on Keras' GitHub.

A workaround for flat parameters ranges is to convert them to Python list using numpy's [`.tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method.